# Can a domain-independent SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance be created

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover, failover-cluster-instance

I know that Always on Availability Groups can be set up on a windows server failover cluster without active directory integration.

But can a SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance high availability solution be created without active directory integration? I couldn't find anything on the subject online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer in Microsoft learn documentation. FCIs require a domain service account, so they can't be domain independent.

Comment: What about the [AD Detached Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265970(v=ws.11)) and [Domain-independent AG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/domain-independent-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: As I've understood it, you can create domain-independent AGs and WSFCs, but FCIs always require a domain.